# Error in grub and starting of linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have just recently installed ubuntu 16.04 on my HP laptop. When I had installed it, at the starting the grub menu used to appear, which gave me an option whether I want to boot ubuntu or windows. But from now on recently, whenever I start my computer, then it always boot windows first. And after that, I go into the BIOS mode and from there when I boot Ubuntu, then it shows the grub menu.

Does anyone has any clue as too why is this problem occurring? I tried searching a lot about it but couldn't get a justifiable solution.

Comment: Can you change your boot priority in BIOS to permanently load Ubuntu first? That way you will hit the GRUB menu ever time and only boot to Windows when you select it there?

Answer (score 0):

[Super Grub2 Disc](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) might be of service and is good to have around.

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering what I call a "boot coup." I have a [Web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) that covers this topic in detail.

My first suggestion is to use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows to adjust your boot order. If your firmware is functioning normally, this tool should enable you to set Ubuntu first, and that should be the end of the problem, at least for a while. (Unfortunately, all OSes have a tendency to try to gain control of the boot process, so such problems tend to recur from time to time.)

If that fails, then chances are you're looking at a firmware bug and/or corrupted boot manager NVRAM settings. Since you say it used to work, chances are you can correct the problem by resetting the firmware to its default and then possibly adding a new entry for GRUB. You can do this using EasyUEFI in Windows or `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu. (It would have to be a boot of the Ubuntu installer/emergency disc, or you'd need to use my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or something similar on a USB drive to boot Ubuntu on a one-time basis.) Check the existing entries so you can re-create them. In a worst-case scenario, [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can re-install GRUB, but this approach is overkill and, in rare circumstances, can create new problems.